# Distribution of time spent above $0$ by a Brownian Bridge.

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, simulation

Let's say I have a Brownian motion, such that I know its value at time 0 (0) and time T (also 0). I am trying to evaluate the time spent above 0 between time 0 and T.

Obviously I know that the average of this value is 1/2, but is there a way to know the full law of that duration? Or are there other known theoretical results for this? I am guessing this is a fairly common problem but I am unable to find references for this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

Yes the time spent above zero by the trajectory of a Brownian bridge  is a uniform random variable, see Exercise 3.9 in  Chapter 12 of  *Continuous Martingales and Brownian Motion* by Revuz and Yor.

Answer (score 5):

Did told me this is a well known result, though Googling confirms that it is not very easy to find on the internet (as you probably realised)

For a Brownian Bridge $X$ with $X_0=0=X_1$, the distribution is a Uniform distribution on $[0,1]$. This result is due to Levy. I found this in a book called **Handbook of Beta distribution and its applications** page 193.

(I was able to view the part of this book for this answer on Google.)

Notice the Arcsin law for a Brownian motion says the amount of time spent by a Brownian motion above $0$ is  Beta distribution with parameters  $(1/2, 1/2)$ and uniform distribution is Beta distribution with parameter $(1,1)$.

The book claims the results has since been generalised, but does not give any references.